# Syntax for declaring a temp table within a SQL Server unit test

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, unit-testing

I am creating a SQL Server unit test for a stored procedure. I have most of it complete, but I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near the word TABLE

from my auto-generated C# test method. I believe I am declaring my temp table wrong.

Here is the portion of my SQL code where I am declaring the temp table.

```
-- Database unit test for dbo.AutoExpireSchedule
DECLARE  @RC                        as INT,
         @Docid                     as VARCHAR(20),
         @NextExpTime               as DATETIME,
         @NextAssignTime            as DATETIME,
         @Appr                      as INT,
         @IsManualAssign            as BIT,
         @preparer                  as INT,
         @status                    as VARCHAR(5),
         @curTime                   as DATETIME,
         @Approut                   as INT,
         @date1                     as DATETIME,
         @date2                     as DATETIME,
         @nextExpDate               as DATETIME,
         @nextAssignDate            as DATETIME,
         @gap                       as INT,
         @RejectedCount             as INT,
         @TotalReqdAssnCnt          as INT,
         @folder                    as VARCHAR(20),
         @DfltAppr                  as INT,
         @AppInstID                 as INT,
         @tempTable                 as TABLE (id INT identity(1, 1), @DocId, @NextExpTime, @NextAssignTime, @Appr, @IsManualAssign),
         @NO_RESPONSE_FROM_PROVIDER as INT = 3;
```

I have also tried:

```
 @tempTable as TABLE (id INT identity(1, 1), DocId int, NextExpTime datetime, NextAssignTime datetime, Appr int, IsManualAssign bit),
```

@EDIT:

I realized there were some other syntax errors in here. So I have fixed those, however still getting same incorrect syntax near the word table. Here is the current code:

```
             @tempTable as TABLE (id INT identity(1, 1), DocId VARCHAR(20), NextExpTime DATETIME, NextAssignTime DATETIME, Appr INT, IsManualAssign BIT),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed doing it wrong. What you're doing here is declaring a **table variable**. Your table variable should look like the following based on your code:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , DocId varchar(20)
  , NextExpTime datetime
  , NextAssignTime datetime
  , Appr int
  , IsManualAssign bit
)
```

So... no `@` sign in front of the columns in the table variable, throw out the `AS` keywords and all the types should be explicitly declared.

More on table variables can be seen for example on [this link](https://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx).

This might not be what you wish to achieve - if so, please add more information to your question.

Comment: Thank you! I have completely forgotten how to declare a temp table. this has solved the issue.

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd - glad to have helped and if it solved your issue consider marking the reply as the answer so that your question gets marked as answered.

Comment: indeed I shall. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
DECLARE @TableVariable table(id INT identity(1,1),
                             DocId int,
                             NextExpTime datetime,
                             NextAssignTime datetime,
                             Appr int,
                             IsManualAssign bit);
```

No `AS` after the variable's name, and it is preceeded by `DECLARE`, like other variables.